# Tkinter GUI problems

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

im working on a [[image]github](/questions/tagged/github) project but its not going so well.
this code:

```
from tkinter import *

def NewFile():
    new = Label(root, text="about \n")
def OpenFile():
    openf = Label(root, text="about \n")
def About():
    about = Label(root, text="about \n")

root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=NewFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=OpenFile)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

helpmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=About)
body = Label(root, text="")
mainloop()
```

Doesnt work how I need it.
its suposed to write certant messages when you click **`file > new`, `file > open` and `help > about`**.

> ## IT DOES NOTHING

how can I make it do what ***I*** want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *



root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
my_label = Label(root, text="Select Menu")
my_label.place(x=10,y=10)

def my_command(query):
    my_label.config(text=query)

menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=lambda x = "New":my_command(x))
filemenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=lambda x = "Open...":my_command(x))
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)

helpmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=lambda x = "About...":my_command(x))
body = Label(root, text="")
mainloop()
```

@Lafexlos is correct.
You can use all python types(list,dict,var and more...) on `GUI` design, most important point `how to manage all GUI elements`, so all need an accessible status.

**Don't `destroy` any GUI element, change and reuse it.**

**Don't include any external command to `mainloop`(like:file,network, etc.)**

**All GUI application required 3 critical section : `INIT >> BUILD >> RUN`** Otherwise you got a lot painful.

**Use GUI elements `text` as `variable`, of-course if all element is accesible !**

I hope helpful and accept @Lafexlos answer not my !
This code work on Python2.7

Answer (score 1):

You are not using geometry managers(pack/grid/place) on your widgets so tkinter doesn't show those to you.

Also, instead of creating new labels on every click, you can either create all three in global scope and pack&forget on clicks or just create one Label and change its value depending on your needs.