# How to prevent tkinter button command from executing immediately the program is run

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm working on, **AGAIN** the code in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147541/tkinter-gui-problems)...
so im wondering how to go about doing this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
# ...
def info(text):
    mb.showinfo(text)
# ...
helpmenu.add_command(label="Version", command=info("Not yet realesed"))
# ...
```

what it does is automaticly executes `info()`.
how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `lambda` function to prevent the `info()` from being executed automatically:

```
helpmenu.add_command(label="Version", command=lambda: info("Not yet realesed"))
```

Comment: I will complement answer: It is assumed that the command argument of the `add_command` method is a function that will be called for a particular action. When you write `command = info ("Not yet realesed") `you do not pass the function, but the result of calling the function as an argument. This is the essence of the problem. The solution is to wrap a call of `info("Not yet realesed")` with a lambda(as it done by @Khristos), or to make a function with a 'bound' argument using `partial` from `functools`.

Comment: He shouldn't need to use a lambda, he should be able to pass the function directly to the argument as grigoriy stated (using partial from functools).